# serialize and deserialize XML files c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm going to make a code to serialize and deserialize XML files to and from datagirdview.
for the seralization:
I have 2 XML files one called
person. xml

```
<Person>
    <ID> 1 </ ID>
    <name> jack </ name>
    <Age> 28 </ age>
</ Person>
<Person>
    <ID> 2 </ ID>
    <name> jacline </ name>
    <Age> 22 </ age>
</ Person>
<Person>
    <ID> 3 </ ID>
    <name> theo </ name>
    <Age> 25 </ age>
```

......

empeloyeur.xml

```
<Empeloyeur> 
<ID> 1 </ ID>
 <Job> engineer </ job> 
</ Empeloyeur> 
<Empeloyeur> 
<ID> 2 </ ID>
 <Job> Director </ job>
</ Empeloyeur>
```

.........

I have this code to display the person.xml file contents in a datagirdview:

```
private void fileOpenToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    opf.Filter = "Text documents (.xml) | * .xml";

    if (opf.ShowDialog () == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = opf.FileName;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet ();
        DataSet.ReadXML (path);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables [0];


    }
}
```

but I would like to show that the attribut  of file persone xml file  and the attribue  of  empolyeur.xml and in the same datagirdview ( datagirdview1 )
is that possible ?

for the deserialize xml i have this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "person";
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Age");
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    DataRow row = ds.Tables["person"].NewRow();
    row["ID"] = textBox1.Text;
    row["Name"] = textBox2.Text;
    row["Age"] = textBox3.Text;  
    ds.Tables["person"].Rows.Add(row);
    ds.WriteXml(path);
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox3.Clear();

}
```

but this code gives me in the end only the last attributes. i went  a file that contains several celull   not only the last one I entered

any help please ?

Comment: You can add a relation but as in your sample there is no relation between those 2 XML. Second part of your question is not clear. You are creating a datatable and adding a single row to that, that would be what you get when you serialize.

Comment: I made a mistake this is my seconde xml file 
<Empeloyeur> 
<ID> 1 </ ID>
<name> jack </name>
 <Job> engineer </ job> 
</ Empeloyeur> 
<Empeloyeur> 
<ID> 2 </ ID>
<name> jacline </name>
 <Job> Director </ job>
</ Empeloyeur>
ther is a relation between the two files i wente display in the datagridview <name > from the first file and <job> from the seconde file

Comment: Edit your question to show the relation, it is not understandable here. And also make it clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Xml is case sensitive.  Below I posted update xml files and code

Xml 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <Person>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>jack</name>
    <Age>28 </Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <name>jacline</name>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <name>theo </name>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </Person>
</root>
```

Xml 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <Empeloyeur>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Job>engineer </Job>
  </Empeloyeur>
  <Empeloyeur>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Job>Director</Job>
  </Empeloyeur>
</root>
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME_1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string FILENAME_2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME_1);
            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME_2);

            var results = (from d1 in doc1.Descendants("Person")
                           join d2 in doc2.Descendants("Empeloyeur") on (int)d1.Element("ID") equals (int)d2.Element("ID")
                           select new { person = d1, empelour = d2 })
                          .ToList();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("person");
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(string));

            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { (int)result.person.Element("ID"), (string)result.person.Element("name"), (int)result.person.Element("Age"), (string)result.empelour.Element("Job") }); 
            }

        }

    }
}
```